# How can I make the horizontal scrollbar for a DIV always appear fixed on the bottom of the page?

Tags: css

I have a website which contains a large (and wide) table. The table is placed inside jquery UI tabs.

It looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq3Rg/

For the user this can be somewhat annoying since he has to go all the way to the bottom of the table and page to scroll right.

Is it possible to make the scrollbar always appear **fixed** on the bottom of the page?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368273/making-horizontal-scrollbar-always-visible-even-if-bottom-is-out-of-view

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set a fixed height (and don't use inline-styles):

**[Your altered Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/Tq3Rg/2/)**

**the code:**

```
.top{
   height:10%;
}
.center{
   overflow:scroll;
   height:80%;
}
.bottom{
   height:10%;
}
```

If you really want to have the scrollbars at the very bottom of your page, you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193242/1047823) on how to achieve this without needing custom scrollbars and such stuff.

Comment: I don't know any browser with that behavior. Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 1):

Just set some fixed height to your middle div
like

```
<div style="background:white;overflow-y:scroll;height:400px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom scrollbar to do this, have a look http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ or http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/#.T_RSYxEe4hU.