# How to make scrollbar appear in the bottom of the viewport?

Tags: css

We have long table and I want the horizontal scrollbar to always appear in the bottom of the viewport.

1. We don't want to use a custom sidebar.
2. I've seen this question: [How can I make the horizontal scrollbar for a DIV always appear fixed on the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330745/how-can-i-make-the-horizontal-scrollbar-for-a-div-always-appear-fixed-on-the-bot) but I want the table to be long (and not to set `height` on it) and to have one main scrollbar on the page (we have more widgets).
3. I tried:

   ```
   .containerClass::-webkit-scrollbar { position: fixed; bottom: 0px;}
   ```

   but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, but you should probably explain what you mean with "it didn't work". What happened exactly?

Comment: I'd be careful with `::-webkit-scrollbar` as it only applies the changes to webkit based browsers. Your design will look very different on IE or on FF or on any other non-webkit browser.