# Making horizontal scrollbar always visible even if bottom is out of view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will start this question with a snippet showing almost what I am trying to accomplish.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.long {
  width: 2000px;
}

.header {
 background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="long">
      I am long
    </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a `.sidebar` (left), `.content` (right).

The problem is that I want to have the horizontal scrollbar on `.content` always visible, even when the `body` is not vertical scrolled to the bottom.

As you can see on the pictures, when at the top of the `body`-scrollbar, there are no visible scrollbar on `.content`

### Current result

[image]

### Expected result

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Best way to achieve always showing the horizontal scroll bar is like this:

By default, the horizontal scroll bar only appears when the user hovers over the container or an element in the scroll. Which can be useless if you want the user to know there are more items to swipe/or flick through.

Here I got a list of categories they are list items or simply links. I want them to be displayed along side the horizontal in desktop and in mobile a user can flick through. It can also be used for images, or cards. This is good user experience and better than stacking in mobile.

**To always show the horizontal scroller, in order for users to know there is more content to scroll horizontally.**

Here is the html:

```
// Note I added z-index in case you can't reach the link due to another navbar on top. You can play with z-index if you need to. 
<div class="cool-shadow" style="z-index: 5;">
  <div class="scrollable-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="some-class">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Sports</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">News</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Science</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Programming</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Bla Blah</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css to make them scrollable:

```
.scrollable-nav {
  // First four are essential.
  display: block;
  width: 100%; 
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // You can change these below if you'd like
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: #2f3142;
  z-index: 5;
  
}

// Make sure the navbar-items are inline block.
.scrollable-nav .navbar-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the css to ensure the scroller is always visible.
To always show the x scroll bar for the user to be aware to flick through the items horizontally, especially when they are on mobile or whenever the the links are overflowing regardless of screen size.

```
.scrollable-nav::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
  height: 11px;
}

.scrollable-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  /* should match background, can't be transparent */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
// This one is important.
.scrollable-nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* 
.scrollable-nav::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
  width: 11px; // This one is optional in case you wanna do this vertically too
} */
```

Comment: FYI - this solution doesn't work for Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar mentions that it's non-standard CSS, which sucks, because I couldn't find a Firefox-friendly solution that works as well as this one.

Answer (score 6):

You can make sure the scrollbar is always visible at the bottom of the page by setting the `height` of the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 92vh;
}

.long {
  width: 2000px;
}

.header {
 background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="long">
        I am long
      </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I set the `height` to `92vh`. I could not use `100vh` since that would hide the scrollbar partially due to the margin that's automatically added to the body of the snippets

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not going to work since I want the vertical scrolling on `body` and not on `.content`

Comment: @TryingToImprove I don't know if that will be possible using pure html/css, you might have to use some javascript to add a "fake" scrollbar

Comment: Yea, I am also afraid of that, but not really sure how to do that.. Having a absolute positioned div outside `.content`, with the same length as the content but with fixed height, which change the `.content` scroll position when scrolled?

Comment: You might be able to achieve that using a [scroll listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) and [`Window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to set the scrolling.

Comment: Almost there: https://jsfiddle.net/1m1kegy3/2/ I would love to kill the fixed, but not sure we need

Comment: You could avoid using `position: fixed;` on the scrollbar by setting it to `absolute` and positioning it from the top: https://jsfiddle.net/1m1kegy3/3/

Comment: Scrolling will keep it at the same position, and not move with the viewport.. :/

Comment: Ah. I forgot to check that. I added some code that makes the `left` of the scrollbar "copy" `width` of the sidebar :) https://jsfiddle.net/1m1kegy3/4/

Comment: Thank you for helping out! :) I find a way where the fixed is okay; https://jsfiddle.net/1m1kegy3/6/ 

Your solution works too..

Answer (score 1):

This works but may also create other issues for you page.
Since position absolute is used.

```css
    .wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .sidebar {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 0;
      bottom:0;
      width: 200px;
      background: #333;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    .container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 200px;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    .long {
      width: 2000px;
    }
    .header {
       background: #666;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="long">
      I am long
    </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this css into body

```
body, html {
  height: calc(100vh);
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.element_with_minWidth {
   min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height:95vh;
}

.content {
  width: 2000px;
}

.header {
 background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="long">
      I am long
    </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .long {
  width: 100%;
}  Don't give width in px if the value is exist the viewprt width automatically horizontal scrollbar will be enabled.

Comment: No, the horizontal scrollbar needs to appear when it extending the .container viewbox

Comment: yes currently working fine your code. what you need.

Comment: No, the horizontal scrollbar is only visible when scrolling to the bottom of `body`, should be visible all the time..

Comment: give height to .container. now check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.long {
  width: 2000px;
}

.header {
 background: #666;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="long">
      I am long
    </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really close, but the scrolling on vertical need's to scroll the entire document normally. Currently the `.sidebar` is not changing when scrolling

Comment: @TryingToImprove on pure css it's impossible.
you must use a fake scroll on js for what you want.
If your sidebar will have more content, you will scroll him when you will hover the mouse on sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.long {
  width: 2000px;
}

.header {
 background: #666;
}
.content{height:93vh;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="long">
      I am long
    </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not going to work since I want the vertical scrolling on `body` and not on `.content`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.long {
  width: 2000px;
}

.header {
  background: #666;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header long">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="long">
        I am long
      </div>
      Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long
      text
      <br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long
      text
      <br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long
      text
      <br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long
      text
      <br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long
      text
      <br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long text<br/>Long
      text
      <br/>Long text<br/>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the header to go up when scrolling vertically, remove

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

... from its CSS.

Ref: *"I want the scrollbar on `<body>` element"*: when you're scrolling a website you don't care what element the scrollbar is attached to. All you care is that it's there, it's accessible and usable.