# Why does a list with a scrollbar break an item over two lines

Tags: html, css

If I have an unordered list with a number of items, and a max height set on this list with the `ul` set to `display: inline-block` (or floated). Then the scrollbar seems to take up the space "inside" the list forcing text to wrap around.

How can I avoid this? I don't mind if the scrollbar makes the list wider, I just want the list to take up its natural space.

http://jsbin.com/AzeBuHU/2/edit?html,css,output

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any text wrapping around..

Comment: Does the 5th item not wrap for you?

Comment: So it does. Apologies. Why not just increase the width of the list? Or is the text variable and you don't want wrap ever?

Comment: Yeah it is variable, I am going to set a max-width but I want to be in control of that!

Comment: You want to be in control of _what_ exactly? I don’t really get what your desired outcome is in the different scenarios.

Comment: So in the current example the 5th item breaks even though I don't want it to, but I may want it to hit a certain max width at a certain point wider

Comment: I guess you could add `white-space: nowrap;` to your li elements but then you would get a horizontal scroll bar... seems to be tricky without js

Comment: @hcharge can you use JavaScript at all?

Comment: Strange isn't it! Very annoying

Comment: JavaScript would be overkill for this I feel. I may add ellipsis to the lines with nowrap

Comment: those this help your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149503/putting-a-scrollbar-outside-padded-region

Comment: @Swayze that may help, I can't check atm but I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in the CSS.  That will prevent the list items from wrapping, and add extra space for the scrollbar.

```
li {
    padding-right:20px; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: scroll;` for UL seems to be a fix, but you'll have the scrollbar everytime, even for few items minor to UL height.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ovUPepI/1/edit)**

Comment: hmm yeah that's not going to be ideal as my list will probably be shorter than this most of the time and the scrollbar is in a worst case scenario, sorry!

Answer (score -2):

Do not give max-height, as it will now take more height than that.
You can give ,

height:auto;

Otherwise you can try

overflow:visible;

This will show scrollbars whenever data is more.

Comment: No I need a max-height... As I only want to show upto a certain amount of items

Comment: No, an element with `height:auto` and no `max-height` will of course _not_ show a vertical scrollbar …